# In C#, convert ulong[64] to byte[512] faster?

Tags: c#, optimization

I have a way that converts ulongs to bytes using binary shifts in a for statement but it's not very time efficient. Is there a way to cast a `ulong` array of size 64 directly into a byte array of size 512? This is a section of code that runs thousands of times and I need to save every millisecond so I can in turn save seconds.

Edit:
Right now this is what I'm doing:

```
                for (int k = 0; k < ulongs.Length; k++) {
                    bytes[(k << 3)] = (byte)(ulongs[k] >> 56);
                    bytes[(k << 3) + 1] = (byte)(ulongs[k] >> 48);
                    bytes[(k << 3) + 2] = (byte)(ulongs[k] >> 40);
                    bytes[(k << 3) + 3] = (byte)(ulongs[k] >> 32);
                    bytes[(k << 3) + 4] = (byte)(ulongs[k] >> 24);
                    bytes[(k << 3) + 5] = (byte)(ulongs[k] >> 16);
                    bytes[(k << 3) + 6] = (byte)(ulongs[k] >> 8);
                    bytes[(k << 3) + 7] = (byte)(ulongs[k]);
                }
```

Comment: it might help to post the code that you have that you want to make more efficient.

Comment: I think this is an interesting question as it is a general problem when using other languages DLLs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
unsafe 
{
    fixed (ulong* src = ulongs) 
    {
        Marshal.Copy(new IntPtr((void*)src), bytes, 0, 512);
    }
}
```

This seems to work. I'm not sure if fixed is required, but I lost an entire second during timed tests.

Comment: Fixed is required because the fixed statement prevents the garbage collector from relocating a movable variable. And without fixed your code would not even compile.

Comment: And your version outperforms mine, it's great that you reminded me of Marshal.Copy(), thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Probably the fastest way of doing it is to use `unsafe` and `fixed` constructions. Here's an example:

```
ulong[] ulongs = new ulong[64];
byte[] bytes = new byte[512];

unsafe
{
    fixed (ulong* src = ulongs)
    {
        byte* pb = (byte*)src;
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Count(); i++)
        {
             bytes[i] = *(pb + i);
        }
    }
}
```

Please do not forget to use `/unsafe` compiler switch when compiling the code above.

**Edit: here's modified version of the first code fragment, which runs much faster on my machine:**

```
unsafe
{
    fixed (ulong* src = ulongs)
    {
        fixed (byte *dst = bytes)
        {
            ulong* pl = (ulong*)dst;
            for (int i = 0; i < ulongs.Count(); i++)
            {
                *(pl + i) = *(src + i);
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this code, and when my program was usually running at 3.5 seconds, it jumped to 8.5 seconds. I had high hopes for this, but I'm looking for a way that doesn't include a for statement, just an unmanaged cast (those being the best words I can think of to call what I'm looking for)

Comment: You can unroll for() loop by writing something like "byte[i] = *(pb + i); byte[i+1] = *(pb + i+1); byte[i+2] = *(pb + i+2); ...; byte[i+7] = *(pb + i +7);" inside the for() statement body

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to achieve this using a `struct` and explicit layout instructions using the [`StructLayout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute(VS.71).aspx) attribute to force variables to occupy the same space.

That way you could write the value using the `ulong` property and read it using the `byte` array property. This assumes, of course, that `byte` array truly takes up the space you expect and that it isn't using 32 bits to hold the 8 bits of information. I'll have to look that up in the specification, which I have not done yet.

Comment: Nope, the byte[] has some other info, so you get an error when trying to load such a type  because it contains an object field at offset 0 that is incorrectly aligned or overlapped by a non-object field.

Comment: If you know the size of that field, you can probably offset the ulong appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [System.Buffer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.aspx) helper class.

```
ulong[] buffer = null;
int byteLength = Buffer.ByteLength(buffer);
byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[byteLength];
Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, byteBuffer, 0, byteLength);
```