# C# Signed & Unsigned Integral to Big Endian Byte Array, and vice versa using Bitwise way with "best" performance

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, endianness

**2nd edit:**

I think my original test script has an issue, the `10000000` times loop is, in fact, dealing with the same memory location of an array, which makes the `unsafe` version (provided by Marc [here](https://gist.github.com/mgravell/0379c974268d145be7c009615bc33ab4)) much faster than `bitwise` version. I wrote another test script, I noticed that `bitwise` and `unsafe` offers almost the same performance.

> loop for 10,000,000 times
>
> Bitwise: 4218484; UnsafeRaw: 4101719
>
> 0.0284673328426447545529081831 (~2% Difference)

here is the code:

```
unsafe class UnsafeRaw
{
    public static short ToInt16BigEndian(byte* buf)
    {
        return (short)ToUInt16BigEndian(buf);
    }

    public static int ToInt32BigEndian(byte* buf)
    {
        return (int)ToUInt32BigEndian(buf);
    }

    public static long ToInt64BigEndian(byte* buf)
    {
        return (long)ToUInt64BigEndian(buf);
    }

    public static ushort ToUInt16BigEndian(byte* buf)
    {
        return (ushort)((*buf++ << 8) | *buf);
    }

    public static uint ToUInt32BigEndian(byte* buf)
    {
        return unchecked((uint)((*buf++ << 24) | (*buf++ << 16) | (*buf++ << 8) | *buf));
    }

    public static ulong ToUInt64BigEndian(byte* buf)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            var x = (uint)((*buf++ << 24) | (*buf++ << 16) | (*buf++ << 8) | *buf++);
            var y = (uint)((*buf++ << 24) | (*buf++ << 16) | (*buf++ << 8) | *buf);
            return ((ulong)x << 32) | y;
        }
    }
}

class Bitwise
{
    public static short ToInt16BigEndian(byte[] buffer, int beginIndex)
    {
        return unchecked((short)(buffer[beginIndex] << 8 | buffer[beginIndex + 1]));
    }

    public static int ToInt32BigEndian(byte[] buffer, int beginIndex)
    {
        return unchecked(buffer[beginIndex] << 24 | buffer[beginIndex + 1] << 16 | buffer[beginIndex + 2] << 8 | buffer[beginIndex + 3]);
    }

    public static long ToInt64BigEndian(byte[] buffer, int beginIndex)
    {
        return unchecked((long)buffer[beginIndex] << 56 | (long)buffer[beginIndex + 1] << 48 | (long)buffer[beginIndex + 2] << 40 | (long)buffer[beginIndex + 3] << 32 | (long)buffer[beginIndex + 4] << 24 | (long)buffer[beginIndex + 5] << 16 | (long)buffer[beginIndex + 6] << 8 | buffer[beginIndex + 7]);
    }

    public static ushort ToUInt16BigEndian(byte[] buffer, int beginIndex)
    {
        return unchecked((ushort)ToInt16BigEndian(buffer, beginIndex));
    }

    public static uint ToUInt32BigEndian(byte[] buffer, int beginIndex)
    {
        return unchecked((uint)ToInt32BigEndian(buffer, beginIndex));
    }

    public static ulong ToUInt64BigEndian(byte[] buffer, int beginIndex)
    {
        return unchecked((ulong)ToInt64BigEndian(buffer, beginIndex));
    }
}

class BufferTest
{
    static long LongRandom(long min, long max, Random rand)
    {
        long result = rand.Next((Int32)(min >> 32), (Int32)(max >> 32));
        result = result << 32;
        result = result | (long)rand.Next((Int32)min, (Int32)max);
        return result;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        const int times = 10000000;
        const int index = 100;

        Random r = new Random();

        Stopwatch sw1 = new Stopwatch();

        Console.WriteLine($"loop for {times:##,###} times");

        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        for (int j = 0; j < times; j++)
        {
            short a = (short)r.Next(short.MinValue, short.MaxValue);
            int b = r.Next(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue);
            long c = LongRandom(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue, r);
            ushort d = (ushort)r.Next(ushort.MinValue, ushort.MaxValue);
            uint e = (uint)r.Next(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue);
            ulong f = (ulong)LongRandom(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue, r);

            var arr1 = BitConverter.GetBytes(a);
            var arr2 = BitConverter.GetBytes(b);
            var arr3 = BitConverter.GetBytes(c);
            var arr4 = BitConverter.GetBytes(d);
            var arr5 = BitConverter.GetBytes(e);
            var arr6 = BitConverter.GetBytes(f);

            Array.Reverse(arr1);
            Array.Reverse(arr2);
            Array.Reverse(arr3);
            Array.Reverse(arr4);
            Array.Reverse(arr5);
            Array.Reverse(arr6);

            var largerArr1 = new byte[1024];
            var largerArr2 = new byte[1024];
            var largerArr3 = new byte[1024];
            var largerArr4 = new byte[1024];
            var largerArr5 = new byte[1024];
            var largerArr6 = new byte[1024];

            Array.Copy(arr1, 0, largerArr1, index, arr1.Length);
            Array.Copy(arr2, 0, largerArr2, index, arr2.Length);
            Array.Copy(arr3, 0, largerArr3, index, arr3.Length);
            Array.Copy(arr4, 0, largerArr4, index, arr4.Length);
            Array.Copy(arr5, 0, largerArr5, index, arr5.Length);
            Array.Copy(arr6, 0, largerArr6, index, arr6.Length);

            sw1.Start();
            var n1 = Bitwise.ToInt16BigEndian(largerArr1, index);
            var n2 = Bitwise.ToInt32BigEndian(largerArr2, index);
            var n3 = Bitwise.ToInt64BigEndian(largerArr3, index);
            var n4 = Bitwise.ToUInt16BigEndian(largerArr4, index);
            var n5 = Bitwise.ToUInt32BigEndian(largerArr5, index);
            var n6 = Bitwise.ToUInt64BigEndian(largerArr6, index);
            sw1.Stop();

            //Console.WriteLine(n1 == a);
            //Console.WriteLine(n2 == b);
            //Console.WriteLine(n3 == c);
            //Console.WriteLine(n4 == d);
            //Console.WriteLine(n5 == e);
            //Console.WriteLine(n6 == f);
        }

        Stopwatch sw2 = new Stopwatch();

        for (int j = 0; j < times; j++)
        {
            short a = (short)r.Next(short.MinValue, short.MaxValue);
            int b = r.Next(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue);
            long c = LongRandom(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue, r);
            ushort d = (ushort)r.Next(ushort.MinValue, ushort.MaxValue);
            uint e = (uint)r.Next(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue);
            ulong f = (ulong)LongRandom(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue, r);

            var arr1 = BitConverter.GetBytes(a);
            var arr2 = BitConverter.GetBytes(b);
            var arr3 = BitConverter.GetBytes(c);
            var arr4 = BitConverter.GetBytes(d);
            var arr5 = BitConverter.GetBytes(e);
            var arr6 = BitConverter.GetBytes(f);

            Array.Reverse(arr1);
            Array.Reverse(arr2);
            Array.Reverse(arr3);
            Array.Reverse(arr4);
            Array.Reverse(arr5);
            Array.Reverse(arr6);

            var largerArr1 = new byte[1024];
            var largerArr2 = new byte[1024];
            var largerArr3 = new byte[1024];
            var largerArr4 = new byte[1024];
            var largerArr5 = new byte[1024];
            var largerArr6 = new byte[1024];

            Array.Copy(arr1, 0, largerArr1, index, arr1.Length);
            Array.Copy(arr2, 0, largerArr2, index, arr2.Length);
            Array.Copy(arr3, 0, largerArr3, index, arr3.Length);
            Array.Copy(arr4, 0, largerArr4, index, arr4.Length);
            Array.Copy(arr5, 0, largerArr5, index, arr5.Length);
            Array.Copy(arr6, 0, largerArr6, index, arr6.Length);

            sw2.Start();
            unsafe
            {
                fixed (byte* p1 = &largerArr1[index], p2 = &largerArr2[index], p3 = &largerArr3[index], p4 = &largerArr4[index], p5 = &largerArr5[index], p6 = &largerArr6[index])
                {
                    var u1 = UnsafeRaw.ToInt16BigEndian(p1);
                    var u2 = UnsafeRaw.ToInt32BigEndian(p2);
                    var u3 = UnsafeRaw.ToInt64BigEndian(p3);
                    var u4 = UnsafeRaw.ToUInt16BigEndian(p4);
                    var u5 = UnsafeRaw.ToUInt32BigEndian(p5);
                    var u6 = UnsafeRaw.ToUInt64BigEndian(p6);

                    //Console.WriteLine(u1 == a);
                    //Console.WriteLine(u2 == b);
                    //Console.WriteLine(u3 == c);
                    //Console.WriteLine(u4 == d);
                    //Console.WriteLine(u5 == e);
                    //Console.WriteLine(u6 == f);
                }
            }
            sw2.Stop();
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"Bitwise: {sw1.ElapsedTicks}; UnsafeRaw: {sw2.ElapsedTicks}");

        Console.WriteLine((decimal)sw1.ElapsedTicks / sw2.ElapsedTicks - 1);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

**1st edit:**

I tried to implement using `fixed` and `stackalloc`, compare with `bitwise`. It seems that bitwise is faster than `unsafe` approach in my test code.

Here is the measurement:

- after loops of `10000000` times with stopwatch frequency `3515622`

> `unsafe fixed`      - 2239790 ticks
>
> `bitwise`           - 672159  ticks
>
> `unsafe stackalloc` - 1624166 ticks

Is there anything I did wrong? I thought `unsafe` will be faster than `bitwise`.

Here is the code:

```
class Bitwise
{
    public static short ToInt16BigEndian(byte[] buf, int i)
    {
        return (short)((buf[i] << 8) | buf[i + 1]);
    }

    public static int ToInt32BigEndian(byte[] buf, int i)
    {
        return (buf[i] << 24) | (buf[i + 1] << 16) | (buf[i + 2] << 8) | buf[i + 3];
    }

    public static long ToInt64BigEndian(byte[] buf, int i)
    {
        return (buf[i] << 56) | (buf[i + 1] << 48) | (buf[i + 2] << 40) | buf[i + 3] << 32 | (buf[i + 4] << 24) | (buf[i + 5] << 16) | (buf[i + 6] << 8) | buf[i + 7];
    }

    public static ushort ToUInt16BigEndian(byte[] buf, int i)
    {
        ushort value = 0;

        for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            value = (ushort)unchecked((value << 8) | buf[j + i]);
        }

        return value;
    }

    public static uint ToUInt32BigEndian(byte[] buf, int i)
    {
        uint value = 0;

        for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            value = unchecked((value << 8) | buf[j + i]);
        }

        return value;
    }

    public static ulong ToUInt64BigEndian(byte[] buf, int i)
    {
        ulong value = 0;

        for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            value = unchecked((value << 8) | buf[i + j]);
        }

        return value;
    }
}

class Unsafe
{
    public static short ToInt16BigEndian(byte[] buf, int i)
    {
        byte[] arr = new byte[2];

        arr[0] = buf[i + 1];
        arr[1] = buf[i];

        unsafe
        {
            fixed (byte* ptr = arr)
            {
                return *(short*)ptr;
            }
        }
    }

    public static int ToInt32BigEndian(byte[] buf, int i)
    {
        byte[] arr = new byte[4];

        arr[0] = buf[i + 3];
        arr[1] = buf[i + 2];
        arr[2] = buf[i + 1];
        arr[3] = buf[i];

        unsafe
        {
            fixed (byte* ptr = arr)
            {
                return *(int*)ptr;
            }
        }
    }

    public static long ToInt64BigEndian(byte[] buf, int i)
    {
        byte[] arr = new byte[8];

        arr[0] = buf[i + 7];
        arr[1] = buf[i + 6];
        arr[2] = buf[i + 5];
        arr[3] = buf[i + 6];
        arr[4] = buf[i + 3];
        arr[5] = buf[i + 2];
        arr[6] = buf[i + 1];
        arr[7] = buf[i];

        unsafe
        {
            fixed (byte* ptr = arr)
            {
                return *(long*)ptr;
            }
        }
    }

    public static ushort ToUInt16BigEndian(byte[] buf, int i)
    {
        byte[] arr = new byte[2];

        arr[0] = buf[i + 1];
        arr[1] = buf[i];

        unsafe
        {
            fixed (byte* ptr = arr)
            {
                return *(ushort*)ptr;
            }
        }
    }

    public static uint ToUInt32BigEndian(byte[] buf, int i)
    {
        byte[] arr = new byte[4];

        arr[0] = buf[i + 3];
        arr[1] = buf[i + 2];
        arr[2] = buf[i + 1];
        arr[3] = buf[i];

        unsafe
        {
            fixed (byte* ptr = arr)
            {
                return *(uint*)ptr;
            }
        }
    }

    public static ulong ToUInt64BigEndian(byte[] buf, int i)
    {
        byte[] arr = new byte[8];

        arr[0] = buf[i + 7];
        arr[1] = buf[i + 6];
        arr[2] = buf[i + 5];
        arr[3] = buf[i + 6];
        arr[4] = buf[i + 3];
        arr[5] = buf[i + 2];
        arr[6] = buf[i + 1];
        arr[7] = buf[i];

        unsafe
        {
            fixed (byte* ptr = arr)
            {
                return *(ulong*)ptr;
            }
        }
    }
}

class UnsafeAlloc
{
    public static short ToInt16BigEndian(byte[] buf, int i)
    {
        unsafe
        {
            const int length = sizeof(short);
            byte* arr = stackalloc byte[length];
            byte* p = arr;

            for (int j = length - 1; j >= 0; j--)
            {
                *p = buf[i + j];
                p++;
            }

            return *(short*)arr;
        }
    }

    public static int ToInt32BigEndian(byte[] buf, int i)
    {
        unsafe
        {
            const int length = sizeof(int);
            byte* arr = stackalloc byte[length];
            byte* p = arr;

            for (int j = length - 1; j >= 0; j--)
            {
                *p = buf[i + j];
                p++;
            }

            return *(int*)arr;
        }
    }

    public static long ToInt64BigEndian(byte[] buf, int i)
    {
        unsafe
        {
            const int length = sizeof(long);
            byte* arr = stackalloc byte[length];
            byte* p = arr;

            for (int j = length - 1; j >= 0; j--)
            {
                *p = buf[i + j];
                p++;
            }

            return *(long*)arr;
        }
    }

    public static ushort ToUInt16BigEndian(byte[] buf, int i)
    {
        unsafe
        {
            const int length = sizeof(ushort);
            byte* arr = stackalloc byte[length];
            byte* p = arr;

            for (int j = length - 1; j >= 0; j--)
            {
                *p = buf[i + j];
                p++;
            }

            return *(ushort*)arr;
        }
    }

    public static uint ToUInt32BigEndian(byte[] buf, int i)
    {
        unsafe
        {
            const int length = sizeof(uint);
            byte* arr = stackalloc byte[length];
            byte* p = arr;

            for (int j = length - 1; j >= 0; j--)
            {
                *p = buf[i + j];
                p++;
            }

            return *(uint*)arr;
        }
    }

    public static ulong ToUInt64BigEndian(byte[] buf, int i)
    {
        unsafe
        {
            const int length = sizeof(ulong);
            byte* arr = stackalloc byte[length];
            byte* p = arr;

            for (int j = length - 1; j >= 0; j--)
            {
                *p = buf[i + j];
                p++;
            }

            return *(ulong*)arr;
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        short a = short.MinValue + short.MaxValue / 2;
        int b = int.MinValue + int.MaxValue / 2;
        long c = long.MinValue + long.MaxValue / 2;
        ushort d = ushort.MaxValue / 2;
        uint e = uint.MaxValue / 2;
        ulong f = ulong.MaxValue / 2;

        Console.WriteLine(a);
        Console.WriteLine(b);
        Console.WriteLine(c);
        Console.WriteLine(d);
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        Console.WriteLine(f);
        Console.WriteLine();

        var arr1 = BitConverter.GetBytes(a);
        var arr2 = BitConverter.GetBytes(b);
        var arr3 = BitConverter.GetBytes(c);
        var arr4 = BitConverter.GetBytes(d);
        var arr5 = BitConverter.GetBytes(e);
        var arr6 = BitConverter.GetBytes(f);

        Array.Reverse(arr1);
        Array.Reverse(arr2);
        Array.Reverse(arr3);
        Array.Reverse(arr4);
        Array.Reverse(arr5);
        Array.Reverse(arr6);

        Console.WriteLine(Unsafe.ToInt16BigEndian(arr1, 0));
        Console.WriteLine(Unsafe.ToInt32BigEndian(arr2, 0));
        Console.WriteLine(Unsafe.ToInt64BigEndian(arr3, 0));
        Console.WriteLine(Unsafe.ToUInt16BigEndian(arr4, 0));
        Console.WriteLine(Unsafe.ToUInt32BigEndian(arr5, 0));
        Console.WriteLine(Unsafe.ToUInt64BigEndian(arr6, 0));
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine(Bitwise.ToInt16BigEndian(arr1, 0));
        Console.WriteLine(Bitwise.ToInt32BigEndian(arr2, 0));
        Console.WriteLine(Bitwise.ToInt64BigEndian(arr3, 0));
        Console.WriteLine(Bitwise.ToUInt16BigEndian(arr4, 0));
        Console.WriteLine(Bitwise.ToUInt32BigEndian(arr5, 0));
        Console.WriteLine(Bitwise.ToUInt64BigEndian(arr6, 0));
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine(UnsafeAlloc.ToInt16BigEndian(arr1, 0));
        Console.WriteLine(UnsafeAlloc.ToInt32BigEndian(arr2, 0));
        Console.WriteLine(UnsafeAlloc.ToInt64BigEndian(arr3, 0));
        Console.WriteLine(UnsafeAlloc.ToUInt16BigEndian(arr4, 0));
        Console.WriteLine(UnsafeAlloc.ToUInt32BigEndian(arr5, 0));
        Console.WriteLine(UnsafeAlloc.ToUInt64BigEndian(arr6, 0));
        Console.WriteLine();

        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();

        int times = 10000000;

        var t0 = sw.ElapsedTicks;
        for (int i = 0; i < times; i++)
        {
            Unsafe.ToInt16BigEndian(arr1, 0);
            Unsafe.ToInt32BigEndian(arr2, 0);
            Unsafe.ToInt64BigEndian(arr3, 0);
            Unsafe.ToUInt16BigEndian(arr4, 0);
            Unsafe.ToUInt32BigEndian(arr5, 0);
            Unsafe.ToUInt64BigEndian(arr6, 0);
        }
        var t1 = sw.ElapsedTicks;

        var t2 = sw.ElapsedTicks;
        for (int i = 0; i < times; i++)
        {
            Bitwise.ToInt16BigEndian(arr1, 0);
            Bitwise.ToInt32BigEndian(arr2, 0);
            Bitwise.ToInt64BigEndian(arr3, 0);
            Bitwise.ToUInt16BigEndian(arr4, 0);
            Bitwise.ToUInt32BigEndian(arr5, 0);
            Bitwise.ToUInt64BigEndian(arr6, 0);
        }
        var t3 = sw.ElapsedTicks;

        var t4 = sw.ElapsedTicks;
        for (int i = 0; i < times; i++)
        {
            UnsafeAlloc.ToInt16BigEndian(arr1, 0);
            UnsafeAlloc.ToInt32BigEndian(arr2, 0);
            UnsafeAlloc.ToInt64BigEndian(arr3, 0);
            UnsafeAlloc.ToUInt16BigEndian(arr4, 0);
            UnsafeAlloc.ToUInt32BigEndian(arr5, 0);
            UnsafeAlloc.ToUInt64BigEndian(arr6, 0);
        }
        var t5 = sw.ElapsedTicks;

        Console.WriteLine($"{t1 - t0} {t3 - t2} {t5 - t4}");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] ba)
    {
        return string.Concat(ba.Select(b => Convert.ToString(b, 2).PadLeft(8, '0')));
    }
}
```

**Original:**

I'm confused about the bitwise way to convert *c#* data type `short, int, long` and `ushort, uint, ulong` to a `byte array`, and vice versa.

**Performance** is really really important to me.

I know there is a *slow* way of doing all these using `BitConverter` and `Array.Reverse`, but the performance is terrible.

I know there are basically two more approaches other than `BitConverter`, one is `bitwise`, and the other is `unsafe`.

After research on *StackOverflow* like:

[Efficient way to read big-endian data in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14401270/efficient-way-to-read-big-endian-data-in-c-sharp)

[Bitwise endian swap for various types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19560436/bitwise-endian-swap-for-various-types)

[In C#, convert ulong[64] to byte[512] faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133858/in-c-convert-ulong64-to-byte512-faster)

[Fast string to byte[] conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20273556/fast-string-to-byte-conversion)

I tried and tested `bitwise` method first, combining all these small pieces into one whole picture.

```
15555
43425534
54354444354
432
234234
34324432234

15555
43425534
-1480130482 // wrong
432
234234
34324432234
```

I'm even more confused about all these bit shifting, here is my testing code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        short a = 15555;
        int b = 43425534;
        long c = 54354444354;
        ushort d = 432;
        uint e = 234234;
        ulong f = 34324432234;

        Console.WriteLine(a);
        Console.WriteLine(b);
        Console.WriteLine(c);
        Console.WriteLine(d);
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        Console.WriteLine(f);

        var arr1 = BitConverter.GetBytes(a);
        var arr2 = BitConverter.GetBytes(b);
        var arr3 = BitConverter.GetBytes(c);
        var arr4 = BitConverter.GetBytes(d);
        var arr5 = BitConverter.GetBytes(e);
        var arr6 = BitConverter.GetBytes(f);

        //Console.WriteLine(ByteArrayToString(arr1));
        //Console.WriteLine(ByteArrayToString(arr2));
        //Console.WriteLine(ByteArrayToString(arr3));
        //Console.WriteLine(ByteArrayToString(arr4));
        //Console.WriteLine(ByteArrayToString(arr5));
        //Console.WriteLine(ByteArrayToString(arr6));

        Array.Reverse(arr1);
        Array.Reverse(arr2);
        Array.Reverse(arr3);
        Array.Reverse(arr4);
        Array.Reverse(arr5);
        Array.Reverse(arr6);

        //Console.WriteLine(ByteArrayToString(arr1));
        //Console.WriteLine(ByteArrayToString(arr2));
        //Console.WriteLine(ByteArrayToString(arr3));
        //Console.WriteLine(ByteArrayToString(arr4));
        //Console.WriteLine(ByteArrayToString(arr5));
        //Console.WriteLine(ByteArrayToString(arr6));

        Console.WriteLine(ToInt16BigEndian(arr1, 0));
        Console.WriteLine(ToInt32BigEndian(arr2, 0));
        Console.WriteLine(ToInt64BigEndian(arr3, 0));
        Console.WriteLine(ToUInt16BigEndian(arr4, 0));
        Console.WriteLine(ToUInt32BigEndian(arr5, 0));
        Console.WriteLine(ToUInt64BigEndian(arr6, 0));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] ba)
    {
        return string.Concat(ba.Select(b => Convert.ToString(b, 2).PadLeft(8, '0')));
    }

    public static short ToInt16BigEndian(byte[] buf, int i)
    {
        return (short)((buf[i] << 8) | buf[i + 1]);
    }

    public static int ToInt32BigEndian(byte[] buf, int i)
    {
        return (buf[i] << 24) | (buf[i + 1] << 16) | (buf[i + 2] << 8) | buf[i + 3];
    }

    public static long ToInt64BigEndian(byte[] buf, int i)
    {
        return (buf[i] << 56) | (buf[i + 1] << 48) | (buf[i + 2] << 40) | (buf[i + 3] << 32) | (buf[i + 4] << 24) | (buf[i + 5] << 16) | (buf[i + 6] << 8) | buf[i + 7];
    }

    public static ushort ToUInt16BigEndian(byte[] buf, int i)
    {
        ushort value = 0;

        for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            value = (ushort)unchecked((value << 8) | buf[j + i]);
        }

        return value;
    }

    public static uint ToUInt32BigEndian(byte[] buf, int i)
    {
        uint value = 0;

        for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            value = unchecked((value << 8) | buf[j + i]);
        }

        return value;
    }

    public static ulong ToUInt64BigEndian(byte[] buf, int i)
    {
        ulong value = 0;

        for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            value = unchecked((value << 8) | buf[i + j]);
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

I'm asking a solution that provides *best* **performance**, with **consistent** code style and **cleanness** of the code.

Comment: So what is slow exactly? Converting to byte array or back to number (or both)?

Comment: @Evk hi, the most common approach if performance is not that crucial is using bitconverter. The slowness will occur on both directions, these are the proven fact and I tested on my local machine as well, it is much slower than bitwise method.

Comment: But how much slower is it compared to your performance *requirements*? Blindly trying to optimize without knowing when you've met your goals means that you could spend months trying to eke out better and better performance and ignore the fact that you got "good enough" after one days work and you've neglected to complete the rest of the product.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes. I totally agree with you. I had never used bitwise and unsafe to do such things. Bitconverter is always my first choice. But now this code will be used in financial related stuff, milliseconds or etc means more $$$, that is why I want to tune it at least beat our current implementation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I'm asking a solution that provides *best* **performance**, with **consistent** code style and **cleanness** of the code.

Nope; pick any two. You can't have all three. For example, if you're after the *best* **performance**, then you may have to compromise on some of those other things.

In the future, `Span<T>` (`Span<byte>`) will be pretty useful for this scenario - with several IO APIs gaining support for `Span<T>` and `Memory<T>` - but *for now* your best bet is probably `unsafe` code using a `stackalloc byte*` (or using `fixed` on a `byte[]`) and writing to that directly, using either shifting or masking with offsets in the "other endian" case.

Comment: Marc, thanks for answering my question. I tested with your suggested approach, it seems that `bitwise` method is faster than `unsafe`, since I'm not familiar with `unsafe` code, could you please help to see is there anything that I did wrong, the implementation and/or testing code.

Comment: @Timeless see enclosed; key numbers after the change: `Unsafe: 2149214 Bitwise: 741436 UnsafeRaw: 411032` (with `UnsafeRaw` being what I had in mind) - https://gist.github.com/mgravell/0379c974268d145be7c009615bc33ab4 ; note I haven't actually used `stackalloc` since you already have the arrays - I've gone for `fixed` instead. If you didn't already have arrays to  pin with `fixed`, then `stackalloc` is a useful way to get a small buffer as a pointer. This will all be much prettier in C# vNext with `Span<T>`

Comment: @Timeless note I also looked at a "thunked" version (smashing the pointer into the native type then reversing the bytes in-place in chunks), but it didn't improve the perf

Comment: Tested on my local machine, `UnsafeRaw` about 20% faster than my `bitwise` version, but 80% faster with your testing.

Comment: Marc, I suspect the performance is the same. Because my original test script is not accurate, my loop was dealing with the same byte array, that is why it performs faster.

Comment: @Timeless it will also depend heavily on what runtime you target - I'm using .net core in my console rig, which has some awesome JIT improvements

Comment: I see. Currently we are running on 4.5.1

Answer (score 0):

Implemented and tested with my latest script, you can still further tune it, but the performance difference between `Bitwise` and `Unsafe` is really small.

**Environment:**

```
Intel Core i7-7700 CPU @3.6GHz
8.00 GB
64-bit
Windows 10 Pro
.NET FRAMEWORK 4.5.1
```

**Here is my result:**

```
Loop for 10 x 10,000,000 times

READ VALUE FROM BUFFER ANY CPU

Bitwise: 27270845; UnsafeRaw: 26828068;
UnsafeRaw is 1.65% faster than Bitwise

READ VALUE FROM BUFFER X64

Bitwise: 27210757; UnsafeRaw: 26847482;
UnsafeRaw is 1.35% faster than Bitwise

WRITE VALUE TO BUFFER ANY CPU

Bitwise: 26364519; UnsafeRaw: 26258470;
UnsafeRaw is 0.40% faster than Bitwise

WRITE VALUE TO BUFFER X64

Bitwise: 25728215; UnsafeRaw: 25733755;
UnsafeRaw is -0.02% faster than Bitwise
```

Paste my code here if anyone wants to do their own test.

**Bitwise, read value from buffer**

```
public static short ToInt16BigEndian(this byte[] buffer, int beginIndex)
{
    return unchecked((short)(buffer[beginIndex] << 8 | buffer[beginIndex + 1]));
}

public static int ToInt32BigEndian(this byte[] buffer, int beginIndex)
{
    return unchecked(buffer[beginIndex] << 24 | buffer[beginIndex + 1] << 16 | buffer[beginIndex + 2] << 8 | buffer[beginIndex + 3]);
}

public static long ToInt64BigEndian(this byte[] buffer, int beginIndex)
{
    return unchecked((long)buffer[beginIndex] << 56 | (long)buffer[beginIndex + 1] << 48 | (long)buffer[beginIndex + 2] << 40 | (long)buffer[beginIndex + 3] << 32 | (long)buffer[beginIndex + 4] << 24 | (long)buffer[beginIndex + 5] << 16 | (long)buffer[beginIndex + 6] << 8 | buffer[beginIndex + 7]);
}

public static ushort ToUInt16BigEndian(this byte[] buffer, int beginIndex)
{
    return unchecked((ushort)ToInt16BigEndian(buffer, beginIndex));
}

public static uint ToUInt32BigEndian(this byte[] buffer, int beginIndex)
{
    return unchecked((uint)ToInt32BigEndian(buffer, beginIndex));
}

public static ulong ToUInt64BigEndian(this byte[] buffer, int beginIndex)
{
    return unchecked((ulong)ToInt64BigEndian(buffer, beginIndex));
}
```

**Bitwise, write value to buffer**

```
public static void SetBuffer(this ushort value, byte[] arr, int beginIndex)
{
    arr[beginIndex] = (byte)(value >> 8);
    arr[beginIndex + 1] = (byte)value;
}

public static void SetBuffer(this uint value, byte[] arr, int beginIndex)
{
    arr[beginIndex] = (byte)(value >> 24);
    arr[beginIndex + 1] = (byte)(value >> 16);
    arr[beginIndex + 2] = (byte)(value >> 8);
    arr[beginIndex + 3] = (byte)value;
}

public static void SetBuffer(this int value, byte[] arr, int beginIndex)
{
    arr[beginIndex] = (byte)(value >> 24);
    arr[beginIndex + 1] = (byte)(value >> 16);
    arr[beginIndex + 2] = (byte)(value >> 8);
    arr[beginIndex + 3] = (byte)value;
}

public static void SetBuffer(this short value, byte[] arr, int beginIndex)
{
    arr[beginIndex] = (byte)(value >> 8);
    arr[beginIndex + 1] = (byte)value;
}

public static void SetBuffer(this ulong value, byte[] arr, int beginIndex)
{
    arr[beginIndex] = (byte)(value >> 56);
    arr[beginIndex + 1] = (byte)(value >> 48);
    arr[beginIndex + 2] = (byte)(value >> 40);
    arr[beginIndex + 3] = (byte)(value >> 32);
    arr[beginIndex + 4] = (byte)(value >> 24);
    arr[beginIndex + 5] = (byte)(value >> 16);
    arr[beginIndex + 6] = (byte)(value >> 8);
    arr[beginIndex + 7] = (byte)value;
}

public static void SetBuffer(this long value, byte[] arr, int beginIndex)
{
    arr[beginIndex] = (byte)(value >> 56);
    arr[beginIndex + 1] = (byte)(value >> 48);
    arr[beginIndex + 2] = (byte)(value >> 40);
    arr[beginIndex + 3] = (byte)(value >> 32);
    arr[beginIndex + 4] = (byte)(value >> 24);
    arr[beginIndex + 5] = (byte)(value >> 16);
    arr[beginIndex + 6] = (byte)(value >> 8);
    arr[beginIndex + 7] = (byte)value;
}
```

**Unsafe, read value from buffer**

```
public static short ToInt16BigEndian(byte* buf)
{
    return (short)ToUInt16BigEndian(buf);
}

public static int ToInt32BigEndian(byte* buf)
{
    return (int)ToUInt32BigEndian(buf);
}

public static long ToInt64BigEndian(byte* buf)
{
    return (long)ToUInt64BigEndian(buf);
}

public static ushort ToUInt16BigEndian(byte* buf)
{
    return (ushort)((*buf++ << 8) | *buf);
}

public static uint ToUInt32BigEndian(byte* buf)
{
    return unchecked((uint)((*buf++ << 24) | (*buf++ << 16) | (*buf++ << 8) | *buf));
}

public static ulong ToUInt64BigEndian(byte* buf)
{
    unchecked
    {
        var x = (uint)((*buf++ << 24) | (*buf++ << 16) | (*buf++ << 8) | *buf++);
        var y = (uint)((*buf++ << 24) | (*buf++ << 16) | (*buf++ << 8) | *buf);
        return ((ulong)x << 32) | y;
    }
}
```

**Unsafe, write value to buffer**

```
public static void SetBuffer(byte* arr, ushort value, int beginIndex)
{
    *(arr + beginIndex++) = (byte)(value >> 8);
    *(arr + beginIndex) = (byte)value;
}

public static void SetBuffer(byte* arr, uint value, int beginIndex)
{
    *(arr + beginIndex++) = (byte)(value >> 24);
    *(arr + beginIndex++) = (byte)(value >> 16);
    *(arr + beginIndex++) = (byte)(value >> 8);
    *(arr + beginIndex) = (byte)value;
}

public static void SetBuffer(byte* arr, ulong value, int beginIndex)
{
    *(arr + beginIndex++) = (byte)(value >> 56);
    *(arr + beginIndex++) = (byte)(value >> 48);
    *(arr + beginIndex++) = (byte)(value >> 40);
    *(arr + beginIndex++) = (byte)(value >> 32);
    *(arr + beginIndex++) = (byte)(value >> 24);
    *(arr + beginIndex++) = (byte)(value >> 16);
    *(arr + beginIndex++) = (byte)(value >> 8);
    *(arr + beginIndex) = (byte)value;
}

public static void SetBuffer(byte* arr, short value, int beginIndex)
{
    *(arr + beginIndex++) = (byte)(value >> 8);
    *(arr + beginIndex) = (byte)value;
}

public static void SetBuffer(byte* arr, int value, int beginIndex)
{
    *(arr + beginIndex++) = (byte)(value >> 24);
    *(arr + beginIndex++) = (byte)(value >> 16);
    *(arr + beginIndex++) = (byte)(value >> 8);
    *(arr + beginIndex) = (byte)value;
}

public static void SetBuffer(byte* arr, long value, int beginIndex)
{
    *(arr + beginIndex++) = (byte)(value >> 56);
    *(arr + beginIndex++) = (byte)(value >> 48);
    *(arr + beginIndex++) = (byte)(value >> 40);
    *(arr + beginIndex++) = (byte)(value >> 32);
    *(arr + beginIndex++) = (byte)(value >> 24);
    *(arr + beginIndex++) = (byte)(value >> 16);
    *(arr + beginIndex++) = (byte)(value >> 8);
    *(arr + beginIndex) = (byte)value;
}
```